# Gram Schmidt Orthogonalization Process on Elementary Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Use the Gram Schmidt orthogonalization process to find a unitary matrix $U\in\mathbb{C}^{3×3}$ that diagonalizes $\sum_{i,j=1,2,3}E_{i,j}$.

What I tried: I take the eigenvectors of $\sum_{i,j=1,2,3}E_{i,j}$.
Can I use the GSOP on these eigenvectors? Will this give me the unitary matrix I am looking for?

Can anyone help me with this please? Thanks.

Comment: What is $E_{i,j}$?

Comment: @Lostinspace can you please elaborate your doubt and question more. It would be more helpful to answer your question.

Comment: @Theo Bendit, if I'm not mistaken they are elementary natrices.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix given matrix (call it $A$) is Hermitian, and hence the eigenspaces are automatically perpendicular, and (directly) sum up to $\Bbb{C}^3$. Any basis of eigenvectors will automatically be orthogonal. In order to form an orthonormal basis, you can simply normalise the vectors. Then, put the orthonormal eigenbasis vectors into columns of a matrix, and that will be a fine choice for $U$.

In terms of making use of Gram-Schmidt, it's not entirely clear what you're supposed to do. Normalising an eigenbasis is, rather trivially, using Gram-Schmidt to turn the eigenbasis into an orthonormal eigenbasis (since the projection of each vector onto each other vector is the $0$ vector); all that applying Gram-Schimdt does is normalise the given vectors.

I can think of one other way that one could arguably apply Gram-Schmidt, but it's a little bit far-out, and doesn't have much more substance. I'd recommend using the method above.